# php folder location

Tags: php, directory

what is the difference between **./**folder-name/file.php and **../**folder-name/file.php in php script?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Path is interpreted by operation system you're using:

- `./` - usually means current folder
- `../` - usually means parent folder

If you're in folder `/home/user`, then

- `./folder-name/file.php` will point to `/home/user/folder-name/file.php`
- but `../folder-name/file.php` will point to `/home/folder-name/file.php`, which is 1 level up

Comment: you have a mistake in your second example - still using single .

Answer (score 2):

The first case, ./folder-name/file.php will start in your current directory.

The second case, ../folder-name/file.php will start from the parent directory.

Answer (score 0):

../ is the directory below the directory you're currently in. ./ is the directory you're currently in. For example. If you are currently in /foo/bar. ../test.php is equivalent to /foo/test.php and ./test.php is equivalent to /foo/bar/test.php.

Comment: Directory hierarchy goes up, not down.

Comment: Apologies, yes, above rather than below, though the example is still sound.